# How to draw an CComboBox on setFocus

Tags: mfc

```cpp
HBRUSH CDialog23::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    HBRUSH hbr = CDialogEx::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

    int Element = pWnd->GetFocus()->GetDlgCtrlID();

    if (pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == Element && nCtlColor != CTLCOLOR_STATIC)
    {
        pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
        pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(255, 230, 153));
        hbr = m_Gelb;
        return hbr;
    }
    else
    {
        pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
        pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(255, 255, 255));
        hbr = m_Weiss;
        return hbr;
    }
}
```

With this code, my ComboBoxes are getting colored in yellow, when I set the focus to one of them. However, if the current focus is set to one of the ComboBoxes, all other ComboBoxes are getting colored yellow, when I hover over them using the cursor (without clicking them). Also, the List of the ComboBox doesn't get colored (they are formated as dropdown).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are not checking combo box ID equals focused combo ID. The dropdown combo boxes never receive focus. It is complex control that contains child edit control and this control has ID=1001 (0x03E9). Hence you are getting focus on the window with 1001 ID and all windows by this ID also change the background.
Change logic and use windows handles instead of IDs.
As for the drop-down list is a popup window layered over the combo box window and you will have to change the background using a different approach. You have no control over drop list creation and the only way would be to dynamically subclass this window using a hook.